# Add the same pattern to fields of the same type in Spring Swagger

Tags: spring, swagger, spring-boot-admin

I have a lot of Apis  in my Spring application.
And I need to create a swagger for it.
One of the field types, that I use a lot in different classes is: MyDate.
Which in the swagger I want to be defined as string with a pattern.
I can use the next line in order to show the field in the swagger as string instead of MyDate:

```
new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).directModelSubstitute(MyDate.class, String.class)
```

But is there a way to add the pattern to all the fields from this type automatically?

Thanks.